# Overloading operator[] only for members of a specific class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

**Edit: `MyClass` has been renamed to `ReverseStringAccess` for disambiguation.**

I have a class which encapsulates a `vector<string>`. The class has an overloaded `operator[]` which can be used to read and modify the contents of the vector. This is how it looks (minimally):

```
class ReverseStringAccess {
    public:
        ReverseStringAccess() {}
        ReverseStringAccess(vector<string> _arr) arr(_arr) {}
        string& operator[](int index) {
            return arr[index];
        }
    private:
        vector<string> arr;
};
```

Now I need to be able to modify the contents of each string in the vector without directly accessing the vector (i.e. some sort of `operator[][]` which only works with vectors that are members of this class). The problem is that using `ReverseStringAccess[][]` will result in the default behavior of `operator[]` on strings. For example, this statement:

```
ReverseStringAccess[i][j]
```

would give the j<sup>th</sup> character of the i<sup>th</sup> string in the vector. But I want it to (for example) instead get the (length - j - 1)<sup>th</sup> character of the i<sup>th</sup> string in the vector, where `length` is the length of the i<sup>th</sup> string.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean by “modify the contents of each string in the vector without directly accessing the vector”? Why does your current code not work to modify the strings? Using `myclass[…][…] = x` should do exactly what you want, shouldn’t it?

Comment: _"The problem is that using `MyClass[][]` will result in the default behavior of operator[] on strings."_ Why is this a problem?

Comment: Yes, but what if I, for example, need `myClass[i][j]` to refer to `arr[i][arr[i].size() - j - 1]`, i.e. if I want it to access the string from backwards?

Comment: @WaisKamal That doesn’t really make sense, what is this supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Your description isn't clear. How do you want to use the class? Please describe it *as code* inside the post itself.

Comment: I am not sure what behaviour you exactly want for `MyClass[][]`. You could employ `operator()(size_t vecidx, size_t stridx)` to modify your desired behavior with a close enough syntax.

Comment: @WaisKamal This doesn't make any sense. It seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you specify what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can use a wrapper class that encapsulates a string and interprets indexing in the manner you want.

Comment: I want to be able to access a string from backwards. In this example I am using a vector of strings for simplicity, but what I have is a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @WaisKamal Then you can write some helper class that will support indexing from the end for whatever it wraps.

Comment: So it is not possible to this without a wrapper class?

Comment: Basically you want a wrapper for `std::string` that supports something like `s[-1]` which should equal `s[s.length() - 2]`, right? AFAIK you are not allowed to modify the behaviour of standard classes like `std::string` (and that's good).

Comment: @churill exactly, but without using yet another class.

Comment: Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/9xsGqrsan. What is wrong with _another class_?

Comment: Please specify problem by providing code which uses new feature. Providing test is best strategy (you can start from [this point](https://godbolt.org/z/PWrccT)).

Comment: When you have new information about your problem please [edit] your question to keep it up to date, so other users do not have to read all comments.

Comment: @MarekR I have already edited the question and added an example.

Comment: Why would you want your `[i][j]` syntax do something different from what `[i][j]` does in every single C++ program in existence yet? If you want different semantics, give your function a different name.

Comment: Sorry but this seems to be confusing. I think a better name for `MyClass` in this example would be `ReverseStringAccess`.

Comment: Whatever your class is called, its `operator[]` returns an `std::string&`. Your class has no say in what `std::string&` does or does not do. If you want the result of your `operator[]` behave differently from `std::string`, do not return an `std::string&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `my_object[i][k]` to not invoke `std::string::operator[]` then don't return a `std::string&` from `MyClass::operator[]`, but a proxy that implements the desired `[]`:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass() {}
        MyClass(vector<string> _arr) arr(_arr) {}

        struct MyProxy {
             std::string& str;
             char& operator[](size_t index) { /.../ }
             const char& operator[](size_t index) const { /.../ }
        };

        MyProxy operator[](int index) {
            return {arr[index]};
        }
    private:
        vector<string> arr;
};
```

Comment: The problem here is that `MyClass::operator[]` now has to return a `MyProxy` whereas it should return a `string`.

Comment: @WaisKamal You can easily add a cast operator to `std::string&` to that `MyProxy` class.

Comment: Thank you, I totally overlooked this :')

Answer (score 2):

The question is how to achieve reverse indexing on members of `vector<string>` via `[][]`.

This can be achieved via a wrapper class for std::string:

```
template<typename T>
class reverse_access {
    T& ref;
public:
     // create wrapper given reference to T
     reverse_access(T& ref_)
         : ref(ref_)
     {}

     // reverse access operator []
     auto operator[](size_t i) -> decltype(ref[0])
     { return ref[ ref.size() - 1 - i]; }
     auto operator[](size_t i) const -> decltype(ref[0])
     { return ref[ ref.size() - 1 - i]; }

      // allow implicit conversion to std::string reference if needed
     operator T&() { return ref; }
     operator const T&() const { return ref; }
};

// inside MyClass:
        reverse_access<string> operator[](int index) {
            return reverse_access<string>(arr[index]);
        }
        reverse_access<const string> operator[](int index) const {
            return reverse_access<const string>(arr[index]);
        }
```

And use `return reverse_access<std::string>(arr[index]);` in `operator[]` in MyClass.
The added conversion operator allows implicit conversion to a reference to the original type.

Another option is to use a different operator that can take 2 arguments: `myclass(vec_index,str_index)`:

```
        string::reference operator()(size_t vec_index, size_t str_index)
        {
            return arr[vec_index][ arr[vec_index].size() - str_index ];
        }
        string::const_reference operator()(size_t vec_index, size_t str_index) const
        {
            return arr[vec_index][ arr[vec_index].size() - str_index ];
        }
```

A third solution is to reverse all strings on construction of `ReverseStringAccess`:

```
ReverseStringAccess(vector<string> _arr) arr(_arr) 
{
   for (auto& str : arr)
       std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
}
```

Comment: The same problem: now `MyClass` has to return a `reverse_access<string>` instead of a `string`. Thanks for the better fit name btw :)

Comment: Even though it is `reverse_access<string>` you can still pass it on to any function that takes `std::string`. But if you really want `[]` to return `std::string&` then use the other solution, or just maintain all your strings in reverse.

Comment: @WaisKamal: Added third option to reverse all strings in constructor of your class ReverseStringAccess.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will go with the first option (the third is impractical).